# Allow Silverlight (and Flash) Apps To Remain Full Screen

Tags: flash, silverlight, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I'm writing a Silverlight application that can go full screen (think YouTube full screen). This is simple enough. However, I want to offer the user the ability to KEEP the app full screen even if they click away.

Many users have multiple monitors and so it doesn't always make sense to shrink the app back into the browser. At present, if they make my app full screen they see the "Press ESC to exit full screen" message and then any clicks to apps on their other monitor causes the full screen Silverlight app to shrink back.

I believe this behaviour of Silverlight (and Flash for that matter) is a security feature to prevent people writing apps that remain full screen. However, I'm wondering if there's an "opt in" way of letting users say "I don't mind this app remaining full screen".

I'm also interested in knowing whether this can be done with Flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full screen pinning mode was added to Silverlight 4:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/fullscreen-window-pinning/

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible in Silverlight - as you rightly say there is restricted control when in full screen because of security concerns.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer over the flash "hack" because it's a fair reflection of the situation. i.e. it's not possible to do this in a supported way with Silverlight.

Comment: I'm afraid I've taken the Answer status away as the situation has changed and Silverlight 4 now supports this. I thought I'd pick the now-correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in silverlight 4 using the Content.FullScreenOptions property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.content.fullscreenoptions(v=VS.95).aspx
Demonstration:
http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/06/21/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-31-pinning-full-screen-mode/